# Как реализовать увеличение картинки как на примере?

Tags: html, javascript, css

http://hoff.ru/catalog/myagkaya_mebel/divany/pryamye_tkanevye/cid3148

Comment: А что пробывали сделать вы?
Это не паблик, тут нет готовых решений

Comment: Пока ничего. Заблаговременно решил спросить описание реализации, прежде чем преступить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот плагин [jQuery cloud-zoom](http://www.yellowlemon.net/javascript/images/cloud-zoom)